# Count number of values in a sum formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sum cell and I want another cell to count the number of values that were added together. I am not sure if it is possible to read the formula text itself from within sheets or not.

```
=1+4+2
```

In another cell I would expect it to be `3`.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think google can do this with a spreadsheet formula. It can be done with a user defined function. Assumes formulas are in column A. Try:

```
function countFormula() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
var cell=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
var f=s.getRange(cell,1).getFormula()
var args = f.replace("=","");
var x=args.split("+")
var count=x.length
return count
}
```

Or to remove any math symbol (+,-,/,*, etc.):

```
function countFormulaNumeric() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
var cell=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
var f=s.getRange(cell,1).getFormula()
var args = f.replace("=","");
var myString = f.replace(/\D/g,',');
var x=myString.split(",")
var count=x.length-1
return count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the =count function on your range of cells!

```
=count(A1:A3)`
```

for example will yield a value of three.

Comment: It's a single cell, not a range

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use FormulaText to examine the formula in a cell and so the answer would be

```
=LEN(FormulaText(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FormulaText(A1),"+",""))+1
```

In google sheets there is no FormulaText, but [this reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/c0RVVhH7mLU) shows how to write one. The code is

```
function FORMULATEXT(A1Notation) {
      return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(A1Notation).getFormula();
  }
```

then you can use it in a similar way to Excel (except with quotes around the cell references) like this

```
=len(FormulaText("A1"))-len(substitute(FormulaText("A1"),"+",""))+1
```

Comment: Good to know! I'm strictly in Google spreadsheets though. Thanks

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that , sorry. So it's a bit of code in GS but you can write a short function to retrieve the formula as here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/c0RVVhH7mLU

Answer (score 0):

for:

[image]

```
=COLUMNS(SPLIT(FORMULATEXT(A1), "=+-*/^()"))
```

[image]

arrayformula:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(BYROW(IF(SPLIT(BYROW(A1:A5, 
 LAMBDA(x, FORMULATEXT(x))), "=+-*/^()"), 0, ), 
 LAMBDA(x, LEN(JOIN(, x))))))
```

[image]